# AVFoundation Custom Camera Causing Crash / Memory Pressure?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, avfoundation

I'm making use of AVFoundation to integrate a custom camera into my app... The problem is, I'm getting a rare but still occurring crash due to memory pressure, I'm not sure why as I'm using ARC, and Memory in Xcode is only around 20mb around the time of crash? What's going on?

Here's my code

```
- (void)setupCamera
    {
        self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
        [self.session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
        if ([self.session canAddInput:input]) {
            [self.session addInput:input];
        }

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        if ([self.session canAddOutput:output]) {
            output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
            [self.session addOutput:output];
            [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        }

        self.preview = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
        [self.preview setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
        [self.preview setFrame:self.cameraView.frame];

        CALayer *cameraLayer = self.cameraView.layer;
        [cameraLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [cameraLayer addSublayer:self.preview];

        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in output.connections) {
            if (connection.supportsVideoOrientation) {
                [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
            }
        }

        NSURL *shutterUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"shutter" ofType: @"wav"]];
        self.shutterPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:shutterUrl error:nil];
        [self.shutterPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }

    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
        if (self.doCapture) {
            self.doCapture = NO;

            [self.shutterPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
            [self.shutterPlayer play];

            CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
            void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

            size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
            size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
            size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

            CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            CGContextRef rawContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
            CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(rawContext);
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
            CGContextRelease(rawContext);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

            UIImage *rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];
            CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

            float rawWidth = rawImage.size.width;
            float rawHeight = rawImage.size.height;
            CGRect cropRect = (rawHeight > rawWidth) ? CGRectMake(0, (rawHeight - rawWidth) / 2, rawWidth, rawWidth) : CGRectMake((rawWidth - rawHeight) / 2, 0, rawHeight, rawHeight);
            CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([rawImage CGImage], cropRect);

            UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImageRef];
            CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);

            [self saveImage:croppedImage];
        }
    }

    - (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image
    {
        [self.capturedImages addObject:image];

        NSArray *scrollItemXIB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SellPreviewImagesScrollItemView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *scrollItemView = [scrollItemXIB lastObject];

        UIImageView *previewImage = (UIImageView *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:PREVIEW_IMAGES_SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_IMAGE];
        previewImage.image = image;

        UIButton *deleteButton = (UIButton *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:PREVIEW_IMAGES_SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_BADGE_BUTTON];
        [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIButton *previewButton = (UIButton *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:PREVIEW_IMAGES_SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_BUTTON];
        [previewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addItemToScroll:scrollItemView];
        [self checkCapturedImagesLimit];

        if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1) {
            [self makeCoverPhoto:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];
            [self cells:self.previewImagesToggle setHidden:NO];
            [self reloadDataAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you run it through Instruments - specifically the Allocations template?

Answer (score 0):

Where you set self.doCapture = true? It seems like you allocate a lot of memory for temporary objects. Try to use @autoreleasepool directive:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    self.doCapture = NO;

    [self.shutterPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
    [self.shutterPlayer play];

       ...

    if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1) {
        [self makeCoverPhoto:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];
        [self cells:self.previewImagesToggle setHidden:NO];
        [self reloadDataAnimated:YES];
    }
```

}

Comment: self.doCapture is set upon a button in the interface being pressed

Comment: would you provide crash info?

Comment: It's simply a "Terminated Due To Memory Pressure" crash. I can screenshot an allocations diagnostic with profile if you'd like.

Comment: I had the same problem, when I have no enough space on my devise, and also because autoreleased objects, that hanging in memory for a while. My suggestion: look at this, that helped me a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644899/avcapturesession-get-memory-warning-and-crash-with-no-reason

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have had the same problem ("Terminated Due To Memory Pressure"), and I just changed the setup of the AVCaptureSession from the viewDidAppear to ViewDidLoad. It was growing up to 100mb or so on the iPad, and now it is going up to 14mb with a big image overlay on top.